# Software to make a tiers diagram?

Tags: n-tier-architecture, dia, tiers

i will make a tiers diagram and need a software to creategraphic, need some like this:
http://i.technet.microsoft.com/Bb735136.msdfsvc01(pt-br,TechNet.10).gif

anybody know software, makes this diagram? I see  many diagram with this style, how i can do that?

Comment: That is *not* a UML diagram.  PowerPoint or Word and some clip art are sufficient for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visio is a good, commonly used app for diagrams like this.
Anything with a good set of clipart will work too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something free, try [dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia).

Visio would be my choice for a paid app which can make that diagram.